# How to remove entire attribute with specific namespace?

Tags: php, dom

I have an XML (SVG) like this (only part is included in example):

```
<path id="path3991" sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc" fill="#A05A2C" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3" d="M533.3,1012.4L464,874.9l3.2,0.2l69.1,137.5L533.3,1012.4z"/>
```

and I would like to remove entire attribute that belongs to namespace 'sodipodi'.

Requested result is:

```
<path id="path3991" fill="#A05A2C" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3" d="M533.3,1012.4L464,874.9l3.2,0.2l69.1,137.5L533.3,1012.4z"/>
```

What i do now:

```
$finder = new \DOMXPath($SVG); 
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[namespace::{sodipodi} and not(../namespace::{sodipodi})]");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
     $node->removeAttributeNS(node->lookupNamespaceURI($ns), $ns);
    }
}
```

And the result is:

```
<path id="path3991" nodetypes="ccccc" fill="#A05A2C" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3" d="M533.3,1012.4L464,874.9l3.2,0.2l69.1,137.5L533.3,1012.4z"/>
```

So instead of just removing attribute's namespace I would like to remove entire attribute.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Would regex replace work for you?

```
$SVG = '<path id="path3991" sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc" fill="#A05A2C" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3" d="M533.3,1012.4L464,874.9l3.2,0.2l69.1,137.5L533.3,1012.4z"/>';
$SVG = preg_replace('/sodipodi:nodetypes=["\'][^\'"]+[\'"]/', '', $SVG);

$finder = new \DOMXPath($SVG);
```

Comment: I did that this way:

'/\bsodipodi\b:.*?["|\'].*?["|\']\s/is'

but I would prefer doing it using DOMXPath because all other transformations are done this way.